# What is the name of the song playing at 10:25?

Tags: music, zetsuen-no-tempest

The anime is "Zetsuen no Tempest", in the last episode (#24).

I recall hearing the song even in Kuroshitsuji (Black Butler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece playing at 10:25 in episode 24 is track #9 "Kusaribe" from [the second volume of the OST](http://vgmdb.net/album/38643). 10:25 in the episode corresponds to roughly 0:21 in the track. Here is an excerpt (0:18–0:28): https://clyp.it/kouhf2vp.

I have not seen *Kuroshitsuji*, but I find it vanishingly unlikely that you would have heard this particular piece in it. (All the more so given that *Kuroshitsuji*'s music was apparently composed by Iwasaki Taku, and this piece is stylistically very unlike most of his work.)